# Have feature specs fail on server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using rails feature specs, and 500 errors are not causing tests to fail, because backtraces are causing false-positives on my tests.

When an error occurs on a test, the full backtrace gets dumped to the page, which often (nearly always) includes the text on the page that I am testing for, in the source code.

How do i configure rspec feature specs to fail when the page has a 500 error?

```
expect(page).to have_text("foo") #throws error, test should fail
```

Comment: You could just ensure that the correct page was rendered. Don't think that would pass if you were redirected to a 500 error page.

Answer (score 1):

You could test the response status code eq 200 like this :

```
expect(response.status).to eq(200)
```

Comment: I had to use `expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)` as response was not a property of page.  If you correct your answer to this, I will mark it as the answer.